# Hide Empty Optgroups

Tags: css

I have some dynamically created select menus, and sometimes there were some optgroups without any options inside.

I hid them with a line of CSS code. It worked in Chrome at the time (2016), but revisiting the website I noticed it's no longer working.

```
optgroup:empty{display:none}
```

Is there a way I can tell if it was deprecated? How should I go about hiding optgroup labels if they do not have any options inside?

Comment: According to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aempty), the `:empty` selector is fully supported across all modern browsers. Can you provide an MVE so we can see the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Both the **[`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)** tag and the **[`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)** CSS pseudo-class are **[supported in all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=empty)**, and your code will indeed hide empty groups:

```css
optgroup:empty {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Filled">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Empty"></optgroup>
</select>
```

However, note that when there's a space or newline inside of an element, it is not considered to be empty, as is **[reported by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)**:

> The `:empty` CSS pseudo-class represents any element that has no children. Children can be either element nodes or text (**including whitespace**). Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether an element is considered empty.

As such, the `:empty` selector won't target it in the following example:

```css
optgroup:empty {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Filled">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Empty">
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

In short, to have your empty `<optgroup>` hidden, you need to make sure that there is absolutely **no** whitespace between your opening and closing `<optgroup>` tags.